# Can I re-use the CSS files from jQuery UI?

Tags: css, jquery-ui

Yesterday I used jQuery UI for the first time and I think I'm going to switch from Dojo to jQuery UI.

I noticed that jQuery UI comes with a set of CSS themes.

- Can I use them in my pages for non-jQuery related stuff?
- Are the CSS class names subject to frequent changes?
- Are there any other things and/or best practices I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use them wherever you feel like, just specify the classes you're interested in using.
2. JQueryUI doesn't make a habit of changing its class names, so that shouldn't be much of a concern.
3. Not much more to say except to make sure JQueryUI already handles a particular styling you're looking for before you go to code your own.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I use them in my pages for
>   non-jQuery related stuff?

Yes you can. They are just CSS / images that follow particular naming conventions.

> Are the CSS class names subject to
>   frequent changes?

Probably not. I don't see the UI team changing them in any big way without prior announcement of the changes and reasons for the changes.

> Are there any other things and/or best
>   practices I should be aware of?

Have a look at [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) if you haven't already - it's the easiest way to build themes for your UI components.